# Degree of acceptance of conjugation of verb according to root

Tags: verbs, compounds

The verb *trasalire* should be conjugated (I report the Indicative present tense) as

> Io trasalisco; Tu trasalisci, Egli trasalisce ...

But since the verb may be perceived as a composite of *salire*, it is often used with its conjugation:

> Io trasalgo; Ti trasali; Egli trasale ...

I'm sure this is not the only case of this phenomenon. 
Do you know to which extent this mechanism of compositional usage of a root is accepted by the speaking community and the official grammars?

Comment: Same for *assalire* (*assalisco* / *assalgo*)

Comment: martina, do you know if tha same applies to *scendere* in reference to *trascendere*. In other terms, which is right, *io trascendo* or *io trascio*?

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis I don't understand where would "trascio" come from. I guess the ambiguity arises with verbs in -isc probably?

Comment: @Kyriakos Kyritsis: it would rather be *trascendisco*, but that is wrong, but in this case *trascendo* is the only right form.

Answer (score 5):

I think it all depends whether the speaker "hears" the root. For me it is really difficult to see "salire" in "trasalire", for example; on the other side, I jump when someone says "il papa *benediva la folla", since "benedire" for me is "bene dire", and so I say "il papa benediceva la folla".

Comment: +1 I agree that the solution probably lies in the ear of the listener. For instance, I am much more confortable hearing *benediva* then *benediceva*!

Comment: I, too, prefer *benediva* over *benediceva*, though.